# What are the different influences of outliers regarding the feature scaling methods: standardization VS. normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, normalization, standardization, feature-engineering

I've come to know that normalization (MinMax scaling) and standardization (Z-score normalization) on data have different influences from outliers in the data.
In [About Feature Scaling and Normalization](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html), the author Sebastian Raschka says:

> "(Min-Max scaling...) The cost of having this bounded range - in contrast to standardization
>   - is that we will end up with smaller standard deviations, which can suppress the effect of outliers."

In his book [Python Machine Learning, 2nd Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/python-machine-learning-second-edition), he mentioned:

> "Furthermore, standardization maintains useful information about
>   outliers and makes the algorithm less sensitive to them in contrast to
>   min-max scaling, which scales the data to a limited range of values."

[image]

**What does he mean that MinMax scaling can suppress the effect of outliers compared to standardization?**

**What does he mean that standardization maintains useful information about the outliers and makes algorithm less sensitive to them in contrast to min-max scaling?**

*Can this be explained from the perspective of the equations?*

Standardization: $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$

Normalization: $X_{norm}=\frac{X-X_{min}}{X_{max}-X_{min}}$

Comment: MinMax squishes all the values in [0,1] hence the data points will be more tightly packed as opposed to standardization, which is unbounded. The author claims that MinMax supposedly doesn't maintain the ratio of distance.